# Refactor my Java code to replace attribute access to getters and setters

Tags: java, refactoring, encapsulation, utilities

I just refactored an old Java library and replaced all public attributes with setters and getters.
Now, there are tons of code around that is accessing those old attributes directly.

Does anyone know of a tool that can go through all the hundreds of classes and refactor them to replace the direct access to the setter or getter ?

For example:

```
old.attr = "Hello!";
String c = old.attr;
```

To:

```
old.setAttr("Hello!");
String c = old.getAttr();
```

Is there something around that will do that magic?

Thanks in advance,

Juan

Comment: Not 100% sure of this, but both Eclipse and IntelliJ have smart refactoring tools which likely can replace direct getter/setter access with method calls.  So, I am suggesting that you first try using the tools in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment to Haoyu.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ as your IDE, you can do this:

> right click the public attribute -> refactor -> encapsulate fields

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the fields are already encapsulated.  And I would have to do that for thousands of fields in hundreds of classes.  I need a systematic/bulk processing approach.

Comment: @jfarjona: did you find a way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry @sam_k nope.